# how to pass data from model to view using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have successfully stored the data to database from view. Now thing is i want to retrieve the data from database and show it in the view. Anyone can help from another link or atleast tell me the flow of passing the data. I m working on a form with text fields and buttons

Comment: check http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html

Comment: above one was for form input. now these two is for database
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the rows in questions, you want to do something like this:

```
$data['rows'] = $this->db->get_where('table_name')->result();
```

And then pass this variable to your view:

```
$this->load->view('index', isset($data)?$data:'');
```

And then access it:

```
var_dump($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one of mine
Controller

```
$data['title'] = "title";

$this->db->select("title, content, date")->from("posts")->where('parent', $parent)->where('status', 'publish')->order_by("id", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->result()){
  $data["mainContent"] = $query->result();
}
$this->load->view("pages/header/head", $data); //this sends the mysql to the page
$this->load->view("pages/van");
$this->load->view("pages/footer/footer");
```

View (this is for an unordered list

```
<?php foreach($mainContent as $row):?> Note maincontent above as well.
<ul>
<li> <?php echo $row->title;?></li>
<li> <?php echo $row->content;?></ul>
</ul>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

You would do the same for tables, or posts or whatever.  The foreach will echo data until it runs out